# How to extend Anorm's parser combinators?

Tags: parsing, scala, playframework, anorm

How can I extend Anorm's parser combinators and use the extensions in 
my application? 
I want to create methods similar to SqlParser.get, SqlParser.int, 
SqlParser.str, etc, and expect to extend the SqlParser trait. But when 
I extend SqlParser, I get compilation errors when I try to use the 
existing parser combinator methods:

```
 trait MyService extends SqlParser { 
     def shoesize(id: String): Int = { 
         SQL("select shoesize from person where id = {id}")
         .on("id" -> id).as (int ("shoesize")) 
     } 
 }
```

results in:

> type mismatch; found : MyService.this.RowParser[Int] required: 
>   play.db.anorm.SqlParser.Parser[Int] Error occurred in an application 
>   involving default arguments.

But this compiles:

```
trait MyService  { 
    import play.db.anorm.SqlParser._ 
    def shoesize(id: String): Int = { 
        SQL("select shoesize from person where id = {id}").on("id" -> id)
        .as (int ("shoesize")) 
    } 
}
```

How should I implement my parser combinator methods?

Comment: Thanks for saving me from my own hasty typing, @Dave